# How to properly install IPython on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: software-installation, python, 15.10, ipython

I installed IPython using

```
sudo apt-get install ipython ipython-notebook
```

But when I tried to start it, it complains not finding some components:

```
sudo ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    start_ipython()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 564, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-110>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 381, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 406, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tornado import gen
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 97, in <module>
    from singledispatch import singledispatch  # backport
ImportError: No module named singledispatch
```

Version info:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing ipython notebook with:

```
sudo apt-get install ipython ipython-notebook
```

will automatically install `python-tornado` system-wide (it's a mandatory dependency, see http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/ipython-notebook)

You have the `singledispatch` import issue because you also installed manually a tornado version in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado`.

Try to remove the culprit version with:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado
```

Comment: Manually removing `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado` apparently cured the symptom.  Where/how I installed it -- I have no idea. Also, when starting iPython notebook server, it says `Failed to create /home/qazwsx/.pki/nssdb directory.`

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R qazwsx:qazwsx ~/.pki/`, it seems this folder is owned by root.